# Updating database changes in ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a database field to an ObjectDataSource in an ASP.NET webforms site.

However when I am trying to add the field I recieve the following error:

```
ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'Update' that has parameters: Cat_ID, name, descr, makat, img_path, img_path2, img_tooltip, img_tooltip2, locked, sort, seo_desc, seo_title, seo_key, h1, footer_text, original_id.
```

I have tried regenerating the dbml file, using utilities such as sql metal and editing the object data source myself to no avail.

Here is my ObjectDataSource code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" 
        InsertMethod="Insert" UpdateMethod="Update" OnSelected="ObjectDataSource1_Selected"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="main_dsTableAdapters.CollecTableAdapter">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Cat_ID" QueryStringField="Cat_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="descr" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="makat" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_path" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_path2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_tooltip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_tooltip2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="locked" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sort" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_desc" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_key" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="h1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="footer_text" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Cat_ID" QueryStringField="Cat_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Cat_ID" QueryStringField="Cat_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cat_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="descr" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="makat" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_path" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_path2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_tooltip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="img_tooltip2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="locked" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sort" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_desc" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="seo_key" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="h1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="footer_text" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there certain steps that I should be taking when wanting to edit/add fields in an ObjectDataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that updating the the DBML layouts and associated data set did not replace the existing data source but created a duplicate one with 1 in the name.

The solution was loading the new data source in the ObjectDataSource and refreshing the schema.